# In which Magento table Paypal Sale ID is stored

Tags: magento-1.9

We recently had a requirement to show the "Paypal sale id" in one of the reports and i have been searching the database table where it is showed and unable to find it.Can someone please let me know to which table that i need to look for it.

I have already searched sales_flat_order_payment  & sales_flat_order table and didn't find any thing.

Below is the attached image and i need the Paypal Sale ID ,I'm able to get Paypal Execution ID .ANy suggestions will be of great help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that to the the paypal transaction ID.
That could be found in:

- `last_trans_id` or `additional_information` (JSON) in `sales_order_payment`
- `comment` in `sales_order_status_history`
- `txn_id` in `sales_payment_transaction`

If not the transaction_id then I would expect it in a similar place.

*Update* I realise this is magento 2 I've referenced, sorry I do not know Mangeto 1 but I still hope this helps